# How do I programatically scroll down the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the page loads, I want to use Javascript/Jquery to automatically take the user to the 500px downwards. But it has to seem natural.

How can that be done?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just Javascript: `window.scrollBy(0,500);`

Comment: If you want a lighter version, this is the way to go. You could add a loop so it looks like ScrollTo, the jQuery plugin

Comment: I recall a browser incompatibility with this function. Not sure, but I'd check that first.

Comment: I think IE needs scrollTo() but I'm not sure.

Comment: yes, window.scrollTo(0,500); seems to be the most compatible way, I would recommend using that instead.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the jquery scrollto plugin. It's very easy.

http://plugins.jquery.com/scrollTo/

Comment: +1: had that in mind as well when I read the question subject in the list.

Comment: Is there a lighter version? Just using javascript?

Answer (score 2):

> *Is there a lighter version? Just using javascript?*

You could consider calling `window.location.hash` during onload. Have an element with an ID at about 500px down and just do

```
window.onload = function() {
    window.location.hash = '#foo';
}
```

Oh, the `#` is mandatory for IE compatibility ;)

Answer (score 1):

use the jquery one Jourkey suggested. Cross platform easy to use etc. There is pure JavaScript one you can try, though YMMV on browsers other than IE

"**scrollTo Method**

Scrolls the window to the specified x- and y-offset. "

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536731(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
$().scrollTop(500);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about navigating to some predefined link inside the page. Foe example see URL pointing to the location inside the page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#cite_note-0